# In each row, how can I write a python script to find that set contains the most consecutive values that greater than 1.5?

Tags: python, arrays, list, max

I want to scan a large excel file. I have 99 columns and 20k rows.
For example:
[This is one of rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4PJ4.png)

There are three sets of Consecutive values greater than 1.5

The one has most consecutive values greater than 1.5 is 31.
My question is how can I write a python script to scan whole file and to find that set contains the most consecutive values that greater than 1.5 in each row?

I need some help by using python script. Thank you.

I tired this, and it only give me the consecutive values for 5. But I need the most / maximum count.

```
from itertools import tee, islice

def find_consecutive(the_list, threshold, count=5):
    my_iters = tee(the_list, count)
    for i, it in enumerate(my_iters):
        next(islice(it, i, i), None)
    return (f for f in zip(*my_iters) if all(x > threshold for x in f))

my_list = [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 1.1, 0.7, 0.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.2, 1.9, 1.1, 0.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2, 1.1, 0.2, 1.3, 0.1, 1.6, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.1, 0.2]
list(find_consecutive(my_list, 1.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question, you could use `groupby` to separate the list into groups of values>1.5, and then count the number of items per group, and keep the biggest

```py
max(((l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno), key=lambda p:p[1])
```

gives a pair, being a sublist (enumerated, so of pair (index,element)), and its length.

Let's see how it works on the following list

```py
my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
```

(There are 3 sequences of numbers >1.5: 2,3,4 starting at index 1, 6,7,8,9,8 starting at index 8, and 2,2,2 starting at index 17. We expect answer to be the second).

We start by enumerating the list, since, at the end, you want indexes of the solution (you haven't clearly said that, but your example are described that way). You already know what enumerate does:

```py
list(enumerate(my_list))
```

is

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8), (11, 9), (12, 8), (13, 0), (14, 0), (15, 0), (16, 1), (17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 2), (20, 1), (21, 0)]
```

(Note about the form of this answer: I use `list(...)` or `[...]` list comprehension to exhibit intermediary result. But most of the time, I don't need to build a list, so in the next step, I remove the `list()` or replace the `[]` list comprehension by `()` generator comprehension. Here the `enumerate` will be passed directly to `groupby` in the next step, without the `list()`. Generally speaking, except for exhibiting results, I avoid building explicit list, that use memory, when a generator can do)

Now, we can use `groupby` to split that enumerated iterable into groups of values >1.5 or <=1.5

```py
list(itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5))
```

```
[(False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250e3a0>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250e1f0>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250ecd0>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250e160>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250eb20>), (True, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250ebb0>), (False, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250ec70>)]
```

is a list of pair boolean/iterator, the boolean being the result of the lambda on all the elements of the subgroup. So False for subgroup of values<=1.5, and True for those >1.5. And iterators being iterators to iterate each subgroup.

We are interested only in the True one, those grouping values >1.5

```py
[it for yesno,it in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno]
```

```
[<itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250eeb0>, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250ef40>, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fe9d250e0d0>]
```

Are itertor for each sublist of values >1.5. Unsurprisingly, there are 3 of them in my example. For the show, we can exhibit their content

```py
[list(it) for yesno,it in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno]
```

is

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], 
 [(8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8), (11, 9), (12, 8)], 
 [(17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 2)]]
```

As expected, we have 3 sequences. One with index 1,2,3, and values 2,3,4; another with indexes 8→12, and values 6,7,8,9,8 and the last one with indexes 17,18,19 and values 2,2,2

What we are interested in is also the size of each of this subgroup, not just their content, we can do that computing len. To avoid iterating twice, I use `:=` operator to put the list into a variable

```py
[(l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno]
```

so same code as before, but with `(l:=list(it), len(l))` pair instead of just `list(it)`

```
[([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], 3), 
 ([(8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8), (11, 9), (12, 8)], 5), 
 ([(17, 2), (18, 2), (19, 2)], 3)]
```

And therefore, same result as before, but with pairs containing previous sequence and its length

Almost there. Now we need to keep only the biggest. `max` is there for that task. But we need to help it by saying what should be compared. Here the maximum value is the one with the biggest length, that is the biggest 2nd value of the pair.
Hence the result

```py
max(((l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno), key=lambda p:p[1])
```

is

```
([(8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8), (11, 9), (12, 8)], 5)
```

That is the max, from the `lambda p:p[1]` point of view.

If you only want the index you can now just select it

```py
max(((l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno), key=lambda p:p[1])[0][0][0]
```

returns 8

Everybody love one-liner. But that one may need to be broken into smaller parts, because of what happens if `my_list` is empty or `my_list` doesn't contain any value > 1.5 (if you know for sure it never happens, then that one-liner is a sure thing: as long as max returns something, it is a pair, so first `[0]` is valid. The first part of that pair is a sequence, and that sequence can't be empty (groupby never create empty subsequences), so `[0][0]` is also valid, and returns the first element of that sequence. And this that is an element of an `enumerate`, it is also a pair, so `[0][0][0]` is valid. So, no risk of index error here. But `max` could fail if the list is empty.

Two  solutions for that. Either you first build a list of those sequences, and compute max after

```py
def maxSeq(my_list):
    seqs=[(l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno]
    if len(seqs)==0:
        return None
    else:
        return max(seqs, key=lambda p:p[1])
```

Drawback of that is that it forces to compute an actual list (seqs) when the previous version had only generator (and list, but only for subsequences)

Or you can use a try/except

```py
def maxSeq(my_list):
    try:
        return max(((l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno), key=lambda p:p[1])[0][0][0]
    except:
        return None
```

Alternatively you could add a sentinel to your list to ensure that max argument is never empty

```py
max(((l:=list(it), len(l)) for (yesno,it) in itertools.groupby(enumerate(my_list+[0,2]), lambda p: p[1]>1.5) if yesno), key=lambda p:p[1])[0][0][0]
```

for example can't fail (in the worst case, it will return the index of the last `2`)